# Heroku segfault due to JSON gem using Ruby 1.9.3, not 2.0.0. How can I fix it?

Tags: ruby, json, heroku, segmentation-fault

This started happening randomly a day or two ago. Here's what the CI logs say after the deploy has succeeded and built the slug:

```
Restarting Heroku...
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

Followed by a load of stack-trace stuff:

```
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `load'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `block in load'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `require'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/ps.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/ps.rb:2:in `require'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58:in `require'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator='
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new'
/mnt/home/u2144/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize'
```

It also seems to show a load of Ruby 1.9.1 stuff being used:

```
-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/bin/heroku

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    2 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    3 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    5 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
   10 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   11 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user
```

My gemfile specifies `Ruby '2.0.0'`, so I don't understand what's going on. Is this a Heroku bug, or should I try to fix it somehow by using different gems?

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. Still not found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be because I had something that was causing Heroku to use Ruby 1.9.3. from the command line:

```
bundle exec heroku restart
> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

I switched to using Ruby 2.0 using RVM and that warning went away. However, my CI deploy was still broken. Then I switched it from using `bundle exec heroku...` to just `heroku...` and was fine.